# why an extra value at end of hash?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I wrote a function to convert alist to hash:

```
(defun hash-alist (alist)
  "Convert association list to a hash table and return it."
  (let ((my-hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (dolist (entry alist)
      (if (gethash (car entry) my-hash)
          (error "repeated key"))
      (puthash (car entry) (cdr entry) my-hash))
    my-hash))
```

but when I run it as following, why I get `nil` at the end?

Run:

```
(setq a '(("a" . 2) ("b" . 1)))
(setq b (hash-alist a))
(maphash (lambda (x y) (princ (format "%s:%d " x y) t))
         b)
```

Output:

```
a:2 b:1 nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nil` is the return value of `maphash`. Nothing more than that.

It is the way that you are evaluating the `maphash` sexp that causes the return value to be printed.
If you look in buffer `*Messages*` you might see something like this (depending on how you evaluate the expression):

```
Evaluating...
a:2 b:1 
Buffer `*Pp Eval Output*' is in mode `Emacs-Lisp'.   For info on the mode: `C-h m'.
nil
```

The return value is documented in the Elisp manual, node `Hash Access`.  It should also be, but is not, documented in the doc string.

Comment: i don't quite get it. why the return value also prints here? And my *Message* exactly the same with `nil`. I use `C-x C-e` to evaluate it.

Comment: It is `C-x C-e` that prints the return value (`nil` in this case). It is the sexp itself that prints `a` and `b`, when it is evaluated.

Comment: right. I had known this - just out of my mind and got confused in this particular case. `C-u C-x C-e` will be more obvious.

Comment: It's easy to forget -- a common gotcha that we all need to remind ourselves of from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Every Lisp expression has a value.

`c-x c-e` evaluates an expression and prints the result.

If you evaluate `(+ 1 2)` you see that it evaluates to `3`. If you evaluate a `maphash` expression, then it evaluates to `NIL`. So this is printed.

Since your code calls functions which produce output, you see that output printed before the return value. So there is no extra `NIL`. It is just the `NIL` that is the result.